# Ubuntu xenial 16.04 LTS freezes with every 4.x Kernel

Tags: kernel

I recently upgraded my server to ubuntu xenial 16.04 LTS,
but ever since then it would just freeze randomly, sometimes immediately after boot, sometimes after an hour of uptime.
I installed an old 3.13 Kernel manually and it worked fine for over 2 weeks.
But I really want to use a 4.x kernel, since it supports my tv card by default.
I tried a lot of 4.x Kernels, from 4.2 to 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, every Kernel freezes my system...
The log files dont show any clues.. sometimes theres something like this at the end of line:
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
I have no idea what to do. Can someone help?
The CPU is a g1610 celeron ivy bridge with integrated graphics.
Mainboard is a asrock z68 pro3.
Thanks
Jonas

Comment: How does it work in a 16.04 live session (booting from a USB flash)? If it bahaves then it's time for you to do a fresh install because something went wrong with the upgrade.

Comment: You'd need to find which is the last of [kernel versions](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions) that worked for you, and then [report a bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/) with a keyword `regression`. My guess, something went wrong with kernel intel graphic driver.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - You guess is correct - something went wrong with the Intel driver at least for some flavors by the time 16.04 was released - but it's now outdated information, hence my suggestion to test a live session from a USB flash made out of the latest 16.04.1.

Comment: \* to complement my prev. comment: the bugreport have to be for the latest kernel version *(as the problem persist there)*, but with the mention of the last worked one. Additionally, I'd recommend to save both `dmesg` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` just after the boot of the last worked, and the next, versions; and to compare them with whatever diff utility, e.g. with `gvimdiff`: perhaps would you notice something unusual? You can remove the noise of timestamps at any time with `awk '{gsub(/^\[.+?\]/,"")}1'` being piped to; for example: `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | awk '{gsub(/^\[.+?\]/,"")}1'`.

Comment: @CelticWarrior honestly, as the problem is pinned down to the kernel, I doubt that testing with live cd would change anything. Though even if it would, the only thing it would mean is that its environment for some reason doesn't trigger the problem code path. But the bug is still here, waiting for its solemn hour :Ь

Comment: @Hi-Angel Point taken.